# How to set proxy authentication (user & password) using Python + Selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, firefox, proxy-authentication

I am using Firefox WebDriver in Python 2.7 with Selenium. My python program starts Firefox browser and visits different websites when I run the program. But, I need to set the proxy with authentication, so that when program visits any website, it will visit through the proxy server.

There are some similar questions on SO. But, there is no specific solution for Selenium Firefox WebDriver of Python.

- [Python Selenium Webdriver - Proxy Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295163/python-selenium-webdriver-proxy-authentication)
- [Running selenium behind a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988821/running-selenium-behind-a-proxy-server)

Comment: u may go through this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988821/running-selenium-behind-a-proxy-server

Comment: tried that one. But that doesn't set username and password for authentication.

Comment: Firefox maintains its proxy configuration in a profile. You can preset the proxy in a profile and use that Firefox Profile. so i think u have to change ur existing firefox profile. U will found a lots of resource how to change FF profile for proxy.

Comment: can you please give me some reference that how can I change firefox profile from python program and save it and reuse it..?

Comment: so far i know, selenium can't do it by itself. have to search more for the latest result. but i think u can handle it through python

Answer (score 11):

Dup of: [How to set proxy AUTHENTICATION username:password using Python/Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458816/how-to-set-proxy-authentication-usernamepassword-using-python-selenium?rq=1)

Selenium-wire: https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire

**Install selenium-wire**

```
pip install selenium-wire
```

**Import it**

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
```

**Auth to proxy**

```
options = {
'proxy': {
    'http': 'http://username:password@host:port',
    'https': 'https://username:password@host:port',
    'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1,dev_server:8080'
    }
}
driver = webdriver.Firefox(seleniumwire_options=options)
```

**Warning**
Take a look to the selenium-wire cache folder. I had a problem because it take all my disk space. You have to remove it sometimes in your script when you want.

Comment: Just an addition to your solution. This will only support Python 3+..

Answer (score 8):

In addition to running Firefox with a profile which has the credentials saved. You can do it loading an extension that writes in the `loginTextbox` and `password1Textbox` of `chrome://global/content/commonDialog.xul` (the alert window).

There are already some extensions that will do the job. For instance: `Close Proxy Authentication`

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/close-proxy-authentication/addon-427702-latest.xpi

```
from selenium import webdriver
from base64 import b64encode

proxy = {'host': HOST, 'port': PORT, 'usr': USER, 'pwd': PASSWD}

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.add_extension('closeproxy.xpi')
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.http', proxy['host'])
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port', int(proxy['port']))
# ... ssl, socks, ftp ...
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.no_proxies_on', 'localhost, 127.0.0.1')

credentials = '{usr}:{pwd}'.format(**proxy)
credentials = b64encode(credentials.encode('ascii')).decode('utf-8')
fp.set_preference('extensions.closeproxyauth.authtoken', credentials)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
```

Comment: this plugin is no longer working in new firefoxes, any other idea what we could do?

Comment: New WebExtensions, unlike good old XUL add-ons, usually store their settings in `chrome.storage` not in browser's preferences (so you can't find them in `about:config`). I'd install some new WebExtension which does the job, set their proxy preferences, inspect its storage (`chrome.storage.local.get((res)=>{console.log(res)})`) and then load it dynamically in the geckodriver and set its preferences through `execute_script`.

Comment: Link is not working - I guess you meant that one -> https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/firefox/addon/close-proxy-authentication/ (Seems to be outdated)

Answer (score 5):

You can write own firefox extension for proxy, and launch from selenium. You need write 2 files and pack it.

**background.js**

```
var proxy_host = "YOUR_PROXY_HOST";
var proxy_port = YOUR_PROXY_PORT;

var config = {
    mode: "fixed_servers",
    rules: {
      singleProxy: {
        scheme: "http",
        host: proxy_host,
        port: proxy_port
      },
      bypassList: []
    }
 };


function proxyRequest(request_data) {
    return {
        type: "http",
        host: proxy_host, 
        port: proxy_port
    };
}

browser.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {;});

function callbackFn(details) {
return {
    authCredentials: {
        username: "YOUR_USERNAME",
        password: "YOUR_PASSWORD"
    }
};
}

browser.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
        callbackFn,
        {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
        ['blocking']
);

browser.proxy.onRequest.addListener(proxyRequest, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "My Firefox Proxy",
  "version": "1.0.0b",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "browsingData",
    "proxy",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "downloads",
    "notifications",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "myproxy@example.org"
    }
  }
}
```

Next you need packed this files to zip archive in DEFLATED mode with .xpi at end like **my_proxy_extension.xpi**.

You have two choices:

1. Sign your extension [Firefox extension .xpi file structure: description, contents, creation, and installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865644/firefox-extension-xpi-file-structure-description-contents-creation-and-inst/31043045#31043045)

**OR**

2. Run unsigned. For this step:

   1. Open firefox flags at about:config and set options **xpinstall.signatures.required** to **false**

      **OR**
   2. Update firefox profile in:

      **Windows**: C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref\channel-prefs.js

      **Linux**: /etc/firefox/syspref.js

   Add next line to end of file:

   ```
    pref("xpinstall.signatures.required",false);
   ```

After this steps run selenium and install this extension:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.install_addon("path/to/my_proxy_extension.xpi")

driver.get("https://yoursite.com")
```

Comment: If anyone has an issue getting this working replace `browser` with `chrome` in background.js.  This code uses callbacks which is how chrome does it.  Firefox uses promises.  If you use chrome keyword it will work in compatibility mode.

Comment: works for me after replacing `browser` with `chrome`. Thanks @Guerrilla

Answer (score 0):

There is an example for Firefox + Python but without the authentication [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy). Then you can find other available parameters [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a1b3b478ec458941c03e02e6bc4fea4332b1645e/py/selenium/webdriver/common/proxy.py) in source code. So it looks like you need the following:

```
socksUsername
socksPassword
```

For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *

myProxy = "host:8080"

proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': myProxy, # set this value as desired
    'ftpProxy': myProxy,  # set this value as desired
    'sslProxy': myProxy,  # set this value as desired
    'noProxy': ''         # set this value as desired
    'socksUsername': = ''
    'socksPassword': = ''
    })

driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy)
```

or with preferences:

```
driverPref = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driverPref.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
.
.
.
driverPref.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', proxyHost)
driverPref.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', proxyPort)
driverPref.update_preferences()

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=driverPref)
```

**EDIT**:

I looked at it again and it seems that it is impossible to set authentication details in FF, even manually. The only way is just to remember the details that you have already entered which done by 2 parameters:

```
signon.autologin.proxy=true
network.websocket.enabled=false
```

that can be configured with the `set_preference()` method. You can also manually view all FF options by browsing to `about:config`.

Comment: None of these set the username and password for proxy authentication...

Comment: @RafayetUllah Yeah, you're probably right. Have a look at the edit.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I got the solution. Saved the firefox profile with proxy manually entered and running firefox with specific firefox profile. It works fine for cross platform...

Comment: @RafayetUllah That's a great idea. Please post it as an answer here and accept it so other users will be able to see it too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I will be adding the answer  here.

Comment: how can i set http proxy username/password dynamically?

Comment: @RafayetUllah I come across this problem recently. can you share your solution?

Comment: @allenwang me too, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @TintinabulatorZea Not yet. What I can do is only to get around this problem by exhibiting proxy in a profile. I still cannot figure out how to set proxy/password. anyone got any idea?

Comment: @EugeneS but how to do with GeckoDriver?

Answer (score 0):

In an addition to the answer with extension.

You can also use form filling to dynamically change credentials on your proxy. Just load the extension page, fill the form automatically and click save!

Answer (score 0):

We can switch to authentication alert box and enter username password manually.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl_port', int(ProxyPort))
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl', ProxyHost)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", ProxyHost)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(ProxyPort))

webdriver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path=GECKO_DRIVER_PATH)

webdriver.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com/")
try:
    alert = webdriver.switch_to_alert()
    print("switched to alert window")
    alert.send_keys(proxy_username + Keys.TAB + proxy_password)
    alert.accept()
    webdriver.switch_to.default_content()
except Exception:
    print("Error in alert switch")
    pass
```