# How to send text on a proxy authentication alert box on Firefox with selenium

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver, proxy-authentication

I am trying to handle proxy authentication. I cannot find a way at all. How can I send text to a proxy authentication alert box that pops up when you only type the host and port.

Comment: Have you checked [How to set proxy authentication (user & password) using python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38304253/2745495)? Also, is there a particular reason you tagged this only with `python` (and not with [`selenium`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selenium/info) and its other related tags)?

Comment: Yes I did check @GinoMempin it's no longer working and I don't have permission to tag this with selenium