# Adding proxy to Firefox driver - Selenium - Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I am trying to add proxies in Firefox driver (which do have authentication). Though I set the proxy by the below code, it is not clear to add authentication for the proxies.

```
 myProxy = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80"

proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': myProxy, 
    'ftpProxy': myProxy,  
    'sslProxy': myProxy,  
    'noProxy': ''
})

driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy)
```

I have gone through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304253/how-to-set-proxy-authentication-user-password-using-python-selenium) for authentication but it is also not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I did not get any error. While testing my proxy with https://www.whatismyip.com/, I found that the proxy wasn't working as my system IP was shown there.

Comment: Did you try below code?

Comment: I am using Python. And you have given solution in Java itseems. I am trying to understand the code. Will try,

Comment: Ah okay. Yeah please change and see it it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I was (finally) able to get to work.  I wasn't able to change the port - I didn't see anything to do that in the proxy.py file either, but I will admit I didn't look too hard since my proxies are on port 80 anyway.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy

proxy_use= "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
desired_capability = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
desired_capability['proxy'] = {
    'proxyType': "manual",
    'httpProxy': proxy_use,
    'ftpProxy': proxy_use,
    'sslProxy': proxy_use,
        }
queryURL = "https://insert.yourwebsitetocheckip.here"
browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=desired_capability)
browser.get(queryURL)
```

I have my function doing a lot more than this, so I just pulled out the relevant part.  Looking at this quickly you might not have to import Options - try it without and see if it works.

Comment: tried so many ways, this actaully work. thanks for this