# How to configure proxies in instapy

Tags: python, selenium, instagram, geckodriver, instapy

I have a fully working instagram bot which is made using instapy and it was working fine,
I wanted to add a proxy to instagram so I added this code

```
session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,
password=insta_password,proxy_username='',proxy_password='',
                  proxy_address='8.8.8.8', 
          proxy_port=8080,
headless_browser=False)


with smart_run(session):
    #code here
```

I am using a premium proxy so that is not a problem for sure,
I have read from the documentation to add this block of code, but I am gettig this error now

```
Custom workspace set: "C://Users//Nikhil//Downloads//forthemodernhouses//forthemodernhouses/InstaPy" :]
to be targetted 
  
 already dmmed
  ['livs.cosy.home2019', 'aceservices2021', 'inmovidal', 'gsmwindowsltd', 'braithwaite_gateway', 'fangting_properties']
final to be dmmed 
InstaPy Version: 0.6.13
 ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._. 
Workspace in use: "C://Users//Nikhil//Downloads//forthemodernhouses//forthemodernhouses/InstaPy"
WARNING [2021-05-23 12:39:53] [forthemodernhouses]  Proxy Authentication is not working anymore due to the Selenium bug report: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7239
WARNING [2021-05-23 12:39:55] [forthemodernhouses]  Unable to proxy authenticate
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
INFO [2021-05-23 12:39:55] [forthemodernhouses]  Session started!
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
```

the proxy requires a authentication, so ive added proxy username and password , but as the error says selenioum does not support it, So is there any other way I can add the proxy(not manually), then how

Comment: The `WARNING` suggests you have a broken connection and since you mention that your script **works** fine without proxy, its a good idea to double check your proxy connection.     Also, you mention you are using a **premium** proxy, perhaps it requires authentication too and in that case you need to pass on extra parameters like [this](https://instapy.org/instance-settings#use-a-proxy)

Comment: - Internet Connection Status: error Unable to login to Instagram! You will find more information in the logs above. Firstly, provide **log output** for debugging purposes... Secondly, The error says you are unable to log into instagram due to weak or no internet. *Check if you are able to log into instagram with your proxy in your normal browser.*

Comment: I bought a new proxy and have edited my question can you please have alook at it agian

Comment: What happens when you set `headless_browser=True` ?

Comment: I think it will run the process in a headless_browser i.e without visual display of the browser , anywhich ways I dont want a headless one ,because it increases tha chance of getting banned, also I dont think it has anything to do with proxy

Comment: 1)  It is possible to get banned. Perhaps try the `headless_browser=True` just to see if connection goes through and not perform any activity to look suspicious.    2)  In the above post you set proxy_username='' (blank)  OR proxy_username="some_blah" etc?   3) The selenium error **7239** might require you to use some other method for auth. Can you use try with different browser using the following two parameters `want_check_browser=True` and `browser_executable_path=/...firefox.exe OR /.../chrome.exe`.

Comment: in the newest version for instapy support has already ended for chromedriver

Comment: @vvy yes i added blank just not to reveal my proxy, second thing ,I tried headles browser ,doesnt work either

Answer (score 1):

To avoid entering proxy-credentials manually you may try the following 2 options:

1. Create a browser extension as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65849158/1504247) and call it before your InstaPy session
2. Use the **url authentication** with selenium before you start your InstaPy session: [source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5137#issuecomment-348801543)

```
    from selenium import webdriver  
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()  
    driver.get("https://username:password@host:port")
```

Comment: thank you for this answer ,I tried your second method ,but I am gettin this error selenium.common.exceptions.webdriverexception: message: reached error page: about:

Comment: and I  dont want to do it through an extension

Comment: I have already posted it, after this the session ended directly

Comment: `webdriverexception: message: reached error page: about:` suggests **url** authentication via get request on `https://username:password@host:port` is not supported by the Proxy server. Can you confirm this by manually entering this on a new tab of your browser ?

Comment: This site can’t provide a secure connection <proxyaddress> sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, this is what i got manually

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I've tried to change `browser.py` to use `seleniumwire` instead of `selenium` and it has worked great for me.